# Nested form deletion not working Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a project model, and a project can have many pictures.  The uploading and adding of the multiple photos is working fine.  however on my edit form I have checkboxes for removing whatever pictures are checked, and the subsequent form submision isn't deleting the record.

Here is the output from the ruby debugger

```
(rdb:2) @project.latestprojectpics.detect {|p| p.id==3}.marked_for_destruction?
true
(rdb:2) @project.latestprojectpics.length
1
(rdb:2) @project.save
true
(rdb:2) @project.latestprojectpics.length
1
```

As you can see, the record is marked for destruction, but when saved it doesn't delete.

I have allow_destroy=>true in the model.  And my Delete checkbox is called _destroy.  Everything seems to be wired up correctly.

Using Rails 3.0.4, Ruby 1.9.2, Carrierwave for file uploads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your delete checkbox name from _delete to _destroy.

I believe that _delete is deprecated.

Comment: No problem. Is there any chance you could post a small snippet of your model, controller and view for updating photos?

Comment: Btw, I just implemented something like this using accepts_nested_attributes_for and I followed one of Ryan Bates' screencasts. If you haven't already seen it, check it out at http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1. It goes over deleting too which was really helpful. :)